# String format in C++

Tags: c++, alignment

I want to show a string output in below format.

```
Bill Robinson
Gross Amount: ............ $3575.00
Federal Tax: ............. $ 536.25
State Tax: ............... $ 125.13
```

This is my current source code

```
< left << setw(width)  << setfill ('.') << "Gross Amount : " << showbase << right << setw(currncy) << put_money(grossAmount) <<endl
```

But I am getting this output

```
Gross Amount : ..................$2,344.00
Edaral Tax : ......................$351.60
State Tax : ........................$82.04
```

Comment: Please provide source code you have now.

Comment: Which part of the output do you have problems with? What have you tried? How did and didn't that work? Instead of the expected output, what was your actual output?

Comment: FWIW, [`std::internal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be done like this?
To prevent any troubles with locale I removed `put_money` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct data {
    data(string _s, float _f) : s(_s), f(_f) {}
    string s;
    float f;
};

int main() {
    const int width = 36;

    vector<data> d;
    d.push_back(data("Gross Amount: ", 3575.00));
    d.push_back(data("Federal Tax: ", 536.25));
    d.push_back(data("State Tax: ", 125.13));

    cout<<"Bill Robinson"<<endl;
    for (data a : d) {
        cout << setfill ('.') << a.s << setw(width - a.s.size()) << "$" << setfill (' ') << setw(7) << fixed << setprecision(2) << (a.f) <<endl;
    }
}
```

Sorry for raw code.